# Vivado 2014.1: Unable to boot .mcs file for SPI Flash Memory on Custom FPGA

Tags: verilog, fpga, spi, vivado

I've written a program for a 3-bit multiplier in Vivado. I was trying to store that program in the SPI Flash memory of the device. The whole process of generating the .mcs file, choosing the configuration memory, uploading the .mcs file, uploading the bitstream file, etc. seems to work fine ( I get no erros ). But when I try to boot the device I get...

> ERROR: [Labtools 27-2254] Booting from configuration memeory device
>   unsuccessful.

I heard there was a problem with Vivado 2014.1 and there is a particular work around but even that didn't work.

http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/61067.html

Or the guide for the workaround.

http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/7-Series-FPGAs/Using-AR61067-for-SPIx4-Configuration/m-p/570312#M8339

So I am wondering is there something I'm missing, like a way to write my code - or important information with the TCL command to create the .mcs file?

Program Version: Vivado 2014.1

Device: Custom FPGA

Comment: UPDATE: I got the process to work on the Nexys 4 but never on a particular custom-made FPGA. However, when using Vivado 2015.2 the FPGA's flash memory was able to be programmed successfully. After doing some experiments it appears that the step that is failing is the actual programming of SPI flash memory device. Creating the .mcs file and even booting the file seems to work fine. Still investigating why the process isn't working for Vivado 2014.1 on a custom FPGA.